# Django when running tests ValueError: Related model cannot be resolved. Related to previous migrations issue

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Had an issue with django migration files not syncing with the db (was getting column not found) due to a Model being renamed. I don't completely understand migrations but after following different stackoverflow answers -  performing fake zero migrations and then adding the manual migration file:

```
# Generated by Django 4.1 on 2022-10-10 00:47

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('campaigns', '0015_blah_blah'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel("PreviousModelName", "ModelName")
    ]
```

I thought the issue had been fixed. I can query the database without errors, I can add new fields to the renamed model and migrate them.  Everything seemed to be working.  But now I've realised that when I run `python manage.py test` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/manage.py", line 25, in <module>
    main()
  File "/code/manage.py", line 21, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 24, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 68, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 1045, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 941, in setup_databases
    return _setup_databases(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 220, in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 78, in create_test_db
    call_command(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 198, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 96, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 349, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 135, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 130, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 96, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 442, in create_model
    sql, params = self.table_sql(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 216, in table_sql
    definition, extra_params = self.column_sql(model, field)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 346, in column_sql
    field_db_params = field.db_parameters(connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1183, in db_parameters
    target_db_parameters = self.target_field.db_parameters(connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1060, in target_field
    return self.foreign_related_fields[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 747, in foreign_related_fields
    rhs_field for lhs_field, rhs_field in self.related_fields if rhs_field
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 734, in related_fields
    return self.resolve_related_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1103, in resolve_related_fields
    related_fields = super().resolve_related_fields()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 712, in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Related model 'app.modelname' cannot be resolved
```

It seems like it throws an error when trying to create the test database. Is there something I need to do to sync the test database?

Comment: to tell django models that you are referring to particular table in your database in your model specify `class Meta` inside meta specify `db_table='table_name_in_your_db'`

Comment: I get the same error whether I set db_table to the old name or the new name.  In the db the name of the table has changed to the new name, but what's interesting is the fields like pk still relate to the old name, so maybe this is the heart of the issue

Comment: If your local table and original table are same then you can fake your migrations.

Answer (score 0):

First delete all migration files and migrate apps manually by doing below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 #This value will generate after makemigration.

python manage.py migrate
```

Hope this will solve your error.

Comment: Thanks but would it not cause issues with the production db when local changes are eventually merged? I thought deleting migration files was bad practice?